# Timeout while performing the DNS lookup

Tags: wordpress, dns, google-search-console

i am trying to verify a website on google webmaster but its show this message (  The connection to your server timed out ) i use all methods and  all failed 
note: when making a page speed test using ( PageSpeed Insights tool )  its return this message ( Timeout while performing the DNS lookup. Ensure that the page loads in a browser and try again. ) 
the website is working fine but with bad performance
nescot.ic.edu.sa

Answer (score 2):

i found the problem it was routing problem cause to many hops becuase of wrong routing from the domain configuration

`tracepath website.domain`

show there is to many hops then no replay routing cross long way to reach the server Which is cause time out problem